# Yet another "question mark" when displaying html

Tags: php, character-encoding, server

I'm moving a PHP ticket app from a VPS server to another, cheaper, less configurable one. Special characters are being shown as question marks.

I've been toying with the charset and set everything to the original charset the app used, latin1. The webserver, the database and each page (via `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`) are in latin1 or iso-8859-1. Nothing works.

The only way to display the special characters correctly is manually setting the codification in the browser to "Western Occidental" Windows-1252.

This did not happen in the old server, just in the new.

What should i check? I do not want to fool around with the app code, it's a mess and wasnt made by me, it has to be related to db/server charset combo.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest using UTF8 instead, but if you already have a lot of data, it can be a pain to convert (there are tools for that though). But more importantly, the **entire line of code** must have the *same* charset. If one is ISO-8859 and other is Windows-1252, I'll be damned if something *doesn't* break.

Comment: Its a large database in latin1, so yes, sucks but will keep it that way. More important, worked fine in the old server.

Comment: That's some default character settings then, you should also add PHP headings. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');` possibly need to specify it in `.htaccess` too.

Comment: Talked with the managed hosting support, the issue was with the output PHP used for default. Set it up to 8859 and worked.